# By clicking a song in a list of songs, a song plays, but the wrong song is playing when the list is filtered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, indexing, filter

For instance, if the user clicks on first song in the filtered list, it plays the first song in an unfiltered list.

The reason why the wrong song might play after the songs are filtered is because the `HomeSongContainer` component is using the musics property to render the list of songs.

The musics property is set to the filtered list of songs, but the `addSongToContext` function is still using the `allSongs` array to get the index of the song to play. This means that the `addSongToContext` function is always playing the first song in the `allSongs` array, even if the user has filtered the list of songs.

The component works as follows:

• When the component mounts, it fetches the list of all songs from the API.

• The user can then search for songs by entering a search term in the search bar.

• The user can also filter the list of songs by artist, category, album, or language.

• When the user clicks on a song, it will be played.

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAllSongs } from "../api";
import { actionType } from "../Context/reducer";
import { useStateValue } from "../Context/StateProvider";
import { SongCard } from "../components/DashboardSongs";
import  { default as MusicPlayer }  from "../components/MusicPlayer";
import Filter from "../components/Filter";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import Dashboard from "../components/Dashboard";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import axios from "../utils/axios";

let scroll = 0;

const Music = () => {
   const [
    {
      searchTerm,
      isSongPlaying,
      song,
      allSongs,
      artistFilter,
      filterTerm,
      albumFilter,
      languageFilter,
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useStateValue();

  const [filteredSongs, setFilteredSongs] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!allSongs) {
      getAllSongs().then((data) => {
        dispatch({
          type: actionType.SET_ALL_SONGS,
          allSongs: data.data,
        });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
      const filtered = allSongs.filter(
        (data) =>
          data.artist.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          data.language.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          data.artist.includes(artistFilter)
      );

      setFilteredSongs(filtered);
    } else {
      setFilteredSongs(null);
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = allSongs?.filter((data) => data.artist === artistFilter);
    if (filtered) {
      setFilteredSongs(filtered);
    } else {
      setFilteredSongs(null);
    }
  }, [artistFilter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = allSongs?.filter(
      (data) => data.category.toLowerCase() === filterTerm
    );

    if (filtered) {
      setFilteredSongs(filtered);
    } else {
      setFilteredSongs(null);
    }
  }, [filterTerm]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = allSongs?.filter((data) => data.album === albumFilter);
    if (filtered) {
      setFilteredSongs(filtered);
    } else {
      setFilteredSongs(null);
    }
  }, [albumFilter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = allSongs?.filter(
      (data) => data.language === languageFilter
    );

    if (filtered) {
      setFilteredSongs(filtered);
    } else {
      setFilteredSongs(null);
    }
  }, [languageFilter]);

  return (

    <div >

   

      <SearchBar />

      {searchTerm.length > 0 && (

        <p >

          Searched for :

          <span >

            {searchTerm}

          </span>

        </p>

      )}

      <Filter setFilteredSongs={setFilteredSongs} />

      <div >

        <HomeSongContainer musics={filteredSongs ? filteredSongs : allSongs} />

      </div> 

      

      <Dashboard/>

      

    </div>

  );
};

export const HomeSongContainer = ({ musics }) => { 
  const [{ isSongPlaying, song }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const addSongToContext = (index) => {

    if (!isSongPlaying) {
      dispatch({
        type: actionType.SET_SONG_PLAYING,
        isSongPlaying: true,
      });
    }

    if (song !== index) {
      dispatch({
        type: actionType.SET_SONG,
        song: index,
      });
    }
  };

  return (

    <>

      {musics?.slice(0, 3).map((data, index) => (

        <motion.div

          key={data._id}

          whileTap={{ scale: 0.8 }}

          initial={{ opacity: 0, translateX: -50 }}

          animate={{ opacity: 1, translateX: 0 }}

          transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: index * 0.1 }}

            onClick={() => addSongToContext(index)}

        >

          <div >

            <motion.img

              whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}

              src={data.imageURL}

              alt=""

              style={{width:"40px", height:"40px"}}

            />

          </div>

          <p >

            {data.name.length > 25 ? `${data.name.slice(0, 25)}` : data.name}

            <span >

              {data.artist}

            </span>

          </p>

        </motion.div>

      ))}

    </>

  );

};

export default Music
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I will appreciate any help!

Comment: I would reconsider using both Redux _and_ local state for the filtered data as you then have two sources of truth for your data. Possibly, this is where the problem is stemming from.